# What type of a function is endl? How do I define something like endl?

Tags: c++, function, iostream

Im new to C++, So the endl is used to end the line as

```
cout << "Hello" << endl;
```

My research around the web tells me it's  a function, if it is so why can we call it without using the "();"

How do I declare a function like that, let us suppose I want to make a function that just tidies up the console everytime I ask for input as

```
string ain()
{
   return "  : ?";
}
```

now instead of having to use this everytime like this

```
cout << "Whats your name " << ain();
```

I want to be able to use it as

```
cout << "Question "  << ain;
```

Just as endl is, I know "()" is not much and this doesn't really do anything huge to save  a ton load of time, but im basically asking this question to figure out why endl can do this.

Comment: *"why can we call it without using the "();""* You don't call it. `std::ostream::operator<<` does (the overload that takes a function pointer as a parameter, number (9), (10) or (11) [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt)). For this to work, the function has to have one of thee specific signatures; [`std::endl`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/endl) happens to be one of those.

Comment: And please note that `std::endl` is rarely needed, although it is widely used. `'\n'` ends a line, without doing the extra stuff that `std::endl` does.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As per cppreference [`endl`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/endl) is a function template with the following prototype:

```
template< class CharT, class Traits >
std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>& endl( std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>& os );
```

[`std::ostream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream)'s [`operator<<`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt) is overloaded to call it upon seeing it.

You can define a similar template yourself:

```
template< class CharT, class Traits >
std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>& foo( std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>& os )
{
    return os << "foo!";
}
```

Now, executing

```
cout << foo << endl;
```

Will print <kbd>foo!</kbd> to the standard output.

Answer (score 4):

`std::ostream` has a member function overload

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& (*func)(std::ostream&));
```

That means you can use

```
std::cout << ain;
```

if `ain` is declared as:

```
std::ostream& ain(std::ostream& out);
```

Its implementation would be something like:

```
std::ostream& ain(std::ostream& out)
{
   return (out << "  : ?");
}
```